# Python Flask - Want to show "Hello [Firstname]

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

)
I´ve followed a very nicely tutorial on how to do signups/logins with Python and SQL.

My SQL is build up like this:

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('Note')
```

I made a new route and view at /dashboard, and here I want to be able to do Hello {{firstname}}, and show users their name.

My auth route:
https://hastebin.com/akopaxuwuq.kotlin

How would I go about this? Could anyone help me here?

Comment: Hello, you need to try to do more code before asking. The next step is work inside the route and then query the database for the string and then make it appear on the webpage for the user. Unfortunately, you have not done any of that yet in the above.

Comment: Ah okay - do you have a guide where I should get Some more information?

Comment: Sure, since you already wrote the class for the database, I would check out one of many YT videos, plenty of people have full FREE courses on flask and as you learn new topics, just watch the video series. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nxzOrLWiic This video would be the next step which is querying the database and adding and removing information from the db inside the route. I like this guy because he goes slow, but he goes too slow for some, but google this type of content to learn new flask topics, or look up articles or read books or all of the above.

Comment: Another great thing are websites like W3Schools, they provide topics with examples of the function/loop etc., in action with great samples. I use that website a lot when i am doing something and realize I need to learn a new topic.

Comment: Thanks. While it didnt seem to work for my use purpose, I will look through his tutorials :-)

Answer (score 0):

First create a login route . Then when the user is logged in you can call the first name with the help of Flask session

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please provide the code for your answer.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/ushbig/for_tideo-.git